# Find out where something has been installed? Or if it has?

Tags: c#, winforms, installation, location

How I can get the location of a program that has been installed on Windows? My C# WinForm is meant to launch the installer for a program, mainly games, and then be able to detect where that program was installed. Or even if it was installed successfully.

Would I have to look in the registry for the location of installed programs, or is there another way? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have to look in the registry. There is [an article here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821775), describing how to do it in C#.